# Long Exposure phtography with milky way and an object

Tags: milky-way, night-photography

I want clear one concept in AstroPhotography with an object in foreground.
When I tried to capture the milky way with focus on infinity and 20 sec of exposure. I went pefect.

But when I tried to capture the milky way with my friend holding torch in foreground, his picture was blurry everytime.

Kindly help me out, how to take a person and milky way both in focus and clear, that too in one shot.

I've attached a picture for example.

[image]

Thanks n BR,
Prashant

Comment: Related: [How do I take a photo with sunset and starry sky at the same time](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82985/how-do-i-take-a-photo-with-sunset-and-starry-sky-at-the-same-time/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're dissatisfied with the depth of field. Not everything in the photo can be in focus at one time. With astrophotography, you probably are going to be using the largest aperture, which is going to make the issue worse.

The best thing to do is take 2 shots and blend them with Photoshop or other such software. Alternatively, if you insist on achieving this in a single shot, then you may have your friend stand further back from the camera, and crop the final image. This will reduce the defocus blur on him.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Myridium. But my concern is - If it is possible to get a person sharp in picture with 20 sec of exposure ?